# Is it possible to show warning in stylelint if already used class being used again?

Tags: html, css, postcss, stylelint

In stylelint or with any other tool is it possible if a developer is writing a class name in CSS file, for example, `.somethingRed {}` he gets a message that this class name has been already used if the similar class name has been used already in the project ?

Comment: When you type a class name in your CSS file in `PhpStorm` for example then PhpStorm gives you a message box where the typed class is already defined in your file. Also PhpStorm gets the class names defined in your HTML. Would that help you?

Comment: @Huelfe Good to know that phpStorm has this feature but can't be sure that everyone involve in project will be having it. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable in stylelint using the [no-duplicate-selectors](http://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/no-duplicate-selectors/) rule.

Comment: Thanks Mr. @jeddy3

Comment: I would like to have that facility with HTML too, not sure if possible or not.